# URL problem in Liferay Portal with a different windowState

Tags: java, portlet, liferay

I have bulid a portlet in [Liferay Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liferay) and have used Ajax. When I open the site without www everything is correct, but when I use www the Ajax request URL is without www and then the response is empty. My Liferay Portal version is 5.1.1 and I use plugins-sdk and use the [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts) 2 portlet and [JSR 168](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR_168_Portlet_Catalog).

I have noticed that if I want to request a portlet with windowState that is not normal? I should request the portlet before with normal state and if a request is with `www` or without `www` the second request have be the same with the normal request (normal windowState).

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : '<portlet:actionURL  windowState="exclusive" >
          <portlet:param name="struts.portlet.action" value="/view/view/search"/>     </portlet:actionURL >' ,
    data : <portlet:namespace/>form_data ,
    success : function (result){
                  jQuery("#<portlet:namespace/>search_results").html(result);
              }
});
```

actionURL is not added www to URL.

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : '<portlet:renderURL  windowState="exclusive" >
           <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/view/view/search"/>     </portlet:renderURL >' ,
    data : <portlet:namespace/>form_data ,
    success : function (result){
                  jQuery("#<portlet:namespace/>search_results").html(result);
              }
});
```

Comment: Try adding commentary rather than just code... It helps people understand why it's a solution to a question.